Gunicorn SIGSEV error when working with GCS
When i run my flask app locally or using uwsgi, it works perfectly. However, when trying to run using Gunicorn, i get a SIGSEV error. I've located the exact piece of code which is causing the error. I have no idea what it could be, i've tried using other versions of gunicorn and google API, but I still get it. Here is the code:
def get_top_level_folders(bucket_name):
    try: 
        # Initialize a storage client
        client = storage.Client()
        bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
        # Get the list of blobs
        blobs = client.list_blobs(bucket)
        # Extract the top-level folder names
        top_level_folders = set()

        for blob in blobs: # This loop causes SIGSEV error
            folder = blob.name.split('/')[0]
            top_level_folders.add(folder)
        
        return list(top_level_folders)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return []

The error doesn't get caught either. When I take away the for loop, it returns an empty list(which is also wrong) but i at least don't get the SIGSEV error. Any help would be greatly appreicated!

Please add pip freeze output. How are you running the code using Flask, uwsgi and Gunicorn? Do you know whether the code is being run multi-threaded? If so, try running it in a single thread to see if the error does not arise.
